# Error in Sub-Menu Template in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, menu

I am using Header-Menu Template as well as Sub-Menu-Header Template. The Main Header Menu Working well but the Sub-Menu isn't working. It doesn't show.

My Wpf XAML code (Sub Menu Header Template) :

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}"  TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"    SharedSizeGroup="Icon" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"   SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"  Margin="6,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  ContentSource="Icon" />
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderHost" Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header"  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"  Grid.Column="2" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" Margin="5,2,2,2" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                <Path Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 0 7 L 4 3.5 Z">
                    <Path.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White"  />
                    </Path.Fill>
                </Path>
                <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Right" HorizontalOffset="-4" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                    <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="RoyalBlue"  BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="RoyalBlue" />
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"   Property="Visibility"  Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"  StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="DeepSkyBlue" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="DeepSkyBlue"   Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent"  Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,3,0,3" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="DeepPink" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Apply to Design :

```
 <Grid>
    <Menu Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource HiMicrosoft}">
        <MenuItem Header="Media" Width="48">
            <MenuItem Header="Open Files" Template="{DynamicResource MI }"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Open Folder" Template="{DynamicResource MI }"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Open Playlist" Template="{DynamicResource MI }"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Open Recent" Template="{DynamicResource MI }"/>
            <Separator Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey} }"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Hide" Template="{DynamicResource MI }"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Template="{DynamicResource MI }"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Playback" >
            <MenuItem Header="Play/Pause" Template="{DynamicResource MI }"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Stop" Template="{DynamicResource MI }"/>
            <Separator Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey} }" />
            <MenuItem Header="Speed" Template="{DynamicResource MI }">
                <MenuItem  Header="Stop"  Template="{DynamicResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

And here is final output screenshot :
[image: SS]

When I click on speed it shows nothing. 
I can't identify the mistake or may be I have used wrong method.

Any help will be appreciate!

If you want I can provide more details. Just comment below.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two errors. First you assigned the wrong template for the SubmenuHeader:

```
<MenuItem Header="Speed" Template="{DynamicResource MI }">
    <MenuItem Header="Stop"
              Template="{DynamicResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
    </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

I think it should be:

```
<MenuItem Header="Speed" Template="{DynamicResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}">
    <MenuItem Header="Stop"
              Template="{DynamicResource MI }"/>
    </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

Second: the submenu does not have a place where to put the submenu items. In the template you need something like the following. Note the stackpanel with the IsItemsHost property. That property indicates where the submenu's items should be placed:

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup" 
       Placement="Right" 
       HorizontalOffset="-4" 
       IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
       AllowsTransparency="True" 
       Focusable="False" 
       PopupAnimation="Fade">
    <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Background="RoyalBlue"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="RoyalBlue">
        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Comment: Doesn't work because my both templates are nearly same. You can say that I don't know the difference between Header and sub header menu template. I am beginner not much expert like you but can you give me some hint what should i do.

Comment: @Abhiverma - I added to my answer as I found another omission.

Comment: Wonderful, rewardable answer. Thanks  a lot bro.